# Flutter showDialog when onWillPop doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dialog

I'm going to let the user show alertdialog when they press Back. There was no error when pressing Back, but no dialog was shown on the screen. It includes webview but I'm not sure that's why. It didn't work even when it was run with a simple text widget instead of a web view.

Here is my code

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  WebViewController? _webViewController;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _completerController =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          print("pop in");
          final shouldPop = await showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Do you want to go back?'),
                actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, true);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, false);
                    },
                    child: const Text('No'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
          print("pop out");
          return shouldPop!;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: WebView(
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _completerController.future
                    .then((value) => _webViewController = value);
                _completerController.complete(webViewController);
              },
              initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              zoomEnabled: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[This is my debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlgxy.png)

only pop in console is appear

Comment: have you tried wrapping WebView with WillPopScope instead of in home?

Comment: I switch my cord like this but occur same problem

MaterialApp-Scaffold-WillPopScope-WebView